# Configuring Zend Server CE on OSX

Tags: zend-framework, terminal

I've installed the Zend Server CE on my computer which runs OSX, but my files won't show up in terminal when I need to configure.  When I open Terminal and input `sudo nano /usr/local/zend/bin/zendct1.sh` the nano text editor opens and I'm supposed to be able to edit various fields, but nothing shows up, and when I try to exit the nano editor, nothing happens.  Terminal accepts my input, but doesn't seem to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Think the command should be ending 'zendctl.sh' not 'zendct1.sh' that's the letter before the dot not a number